# Timer with a button function?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

Can someone help me add this functionality into my code?

I need a timer at the top of the view controller that is related to the button being tapped. This timer would only allow the button to be pushed once a day. How could I do this?

Here is my view controller code.

**Sample code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var emojiPickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var spinButton: UIButton!


    var emojiArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    var reelArray0 = [Int]()
    var reelArray1 = [Int]()
    var reelArray2 = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        emojiPickerView.delegate = self
        emojiPickerView.dataSource = self

        setUpUI()
        addRandomNumbersToReelArrays()

        // Set reels to middle positions
        for i in 0...2 {
            selectEmojiPickerComponentRow(50, component: i)
        }
    }

    func setUpUI() {
        spinButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        spinButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        spinButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 4.0)
        spinButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        spinButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0



    }

    @IBAction func spinButtonTapped() {

        animateSpinButton()

        // Pick 3 random emojis
        for i in 0...2 {
            selectEmojiPickerComponentRow(Int(arc4random_uniform(99)), component: i)
        }
        showFeedbackForWinningSpin()
    }

    func showFeedbackForWinningSpin() {
        if(reelArray0[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] == reelArray1[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] && reelArray1[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] == reelArray2[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]) {
            // JACKPOT
            spinButton.isEnabled = false
            delay(0.8) {
                self.showAlertForJackpot()
                self.spinButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        } else if ((reelArray0[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] == reelArray1[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
            || reelArray1[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] == reelArray2[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)])
            || (reelArray0[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] == reelArray2[emojiPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)])) {
            // Two emojis matched
            spinButton.isEnabled = false
            delay(0.8) {
                self.showAlertForWin()
                self.spinButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    func showAlertForJackpot() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "JACKPOT!",
                                      message: "Congratulations! You won the jackpot!",
                                      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Woohoo!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showAlertForWin() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "YOU WON!",
                                      message: "Congratulations! \nYou got 2 matching emojis! \n\nCan you hit the JACKPOT next time?",
                                      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes I can!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func animateSpinButton() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1,
                       animations: {
                        self.spinButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
                        self.spinButton.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        },
                       completion: { finish in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                            self.spinButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                            self.spinButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
                        })
        })
    }

    func selectEmojiPickerComponentRow(_ row: Int, component: Int) {
        emojiPickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: component, animated: true)
    }

    func addRandomNumbersToReelArrays() {
        for _ in 0..<100 {
            reelArray0.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
            reelArray1.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
            reelArray2.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
        }
    }

    func delay(_ delay: Double, closure: @escaping ()->()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
            deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC),
            execute: closure
        )
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()

        if component == 0 {
            pickerLabel.text = emojiArray[reelArray0[row]]
        } else if component == 1 {
            pickerLabel.text = emojiArray[reelArray1[row]]
        } else {
            pickerLabel.text = emojiArray[reelArray2[row]]
        }

        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Apple Color Emoji", size: 80)
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        return pickerLabel
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think a timer is good fit for that. If the user quits your app the timer would be reset and and then the user could press the button multiple times a day. You should probably use an NSObject or something that persists a reboot, quit and crash.

Answer (score 0):

I've come with a work-around with your requirements. Though it's not the best work-around, it kind of does the job.

1. Configure your button according to change of day. Here is a convenient function:

   ```
   func configureButtonForShowingOnceInADay() {

       spinButton.tintColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
       let now = Date()
       var savedDay: Date?
       /* Check if the app launched for first time or not */
       let appLanuchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ApplicationDidLaunchPreviously")
       if !appLanuchedBefore {
           // App launched for first time, so Mark the app as launched in the UserDefaults
           UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ApplicationDidLaunchPreviously")
           // When App launched for first time, it is must to have a date before today's date.
           // A previous date is required for the button to be enabled for the first time
           savedDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: now)
       } else {
           // App launched multiple times. So read the date from UserDefaults
           savedDay = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "date") as? Date
       }

       // get only the Date portion from now, not with Time
       let today = todaysDate(date: now)

       if let savedDate = savedDay {
           if todaysDate(date: savedDate) == today {
               // Saved date in UserDefaults matches with today. So the button should not be enabled
               spinButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
               spinButton.tintColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, green: 0.501960814, blue: 0.501960814, alpha: 1)
           } else {
               // Saved date in UserDefaults doesn't match with today. So the button should be enabled
               spinButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
               spinButton.tintColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
               UserDefaults.standard.set(now, forKey: "date")
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. A function that will give you the Date portion (June 14, 2017) from a Date object (2017-06-16 04:57:21 +0000)

   ```
   /* A method for converting Date-with-Time to Date-only String */
   func todaysDate(date: Date)-> String {
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
       dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
       return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
   }
   ```
3. Do extra work in your Button's action method. Because if the button is tapped once, it should be disabled for the rest of the day.

   ```
   @IBAction func spinButtonTapped() {
       animateSpinButton()
       // Pick 3 random emojis
       for i in 0...2 {
           selectEmojiPickerComponentRow(Int(arc4random_uniform(99)), component: i)
       }
       showFeedbackForWinningSpin()


       // If the button is Tapped then toggle the button's user interaction property
       sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = !sender.isUserInteractionEnabled
       if sender.isUserInteractionEnabled {
           sender.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
       } else {
           sender.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, green: 0.501960814, blue: 0.501960814, alpha: 1)
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally call `configureButtonForShowingOnceInADay()` from `viewWillAppear(_:)` method:

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       configureButtonForShowingOnceInADay()
   }
   ```